# Setting up nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have a nginx running on a linux ec2 instance.

Here's my configuration file

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/example.com;
  index index.html;
  
  location /hindiscript/ {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:7778;
  }
  
  location /{
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  
  
  
}
```

I have a nodejs server running on port 7778. curl from the instance to http://localhost:7778 is working fine.

When i try to curl http://example.com/hindiscript, I'm getting 301 permanently moved issue. Can someone help here ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/607731

Comment: Went through the answer. Did not help.

Comment: Check the location header. Nginx must be sending a 301 to add back the missing slash if you're visiting `/hindiscript`.

Comment: Please elaborate on your expected behavior. What response should you get instead?

Comment: When I'm curling to http://localhost:7778, I'm getting the 200 ok response. But when i try to access http://example.com/hindiscript, I need to get the same 200 ok response. Instead i'm getting 301.

Comment: check this [digital ocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-reverse-proxy-node-angular)

Comment: @AbhaySrivastav you're getting a 301 because you're telling nginx to expect requests for `/hindiscript/`, with a trailing slash, but you're requesting it without one. If you don't want that, use `location /hindiscript { ... }`